# Detecting touches on UITableView in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, uitableview, touch

i want to animate image when the user press the **cell's buttton**, i created buttons at the end of each cell, when the user press the button then the **image animation** start from that button, what will i do?, I have used **touch begin** function, but it does'nt work on **tableview**.....I want to get x,y position of the touch on the tableview cell's button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];

        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

        CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.view];

        CGPoint xLocation;

        xLocation = CGPointMake(currentTouchPosition.x-35,currentTouchPosition.y-10);

        pressPoint = xLocation;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: i am not clicking on cell, i am clicking on the button, which i have added as a sub view of cell.Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

if you are using button then you can addTarget to that button and do the task in the method registered for that button.Whats the need of using touches began if you are using button? For getting x and y you already have the x y position of the button, use that

Comment: I mean i draw hundred cells and i scroll 90th cell and click on the button so that button bright via animation and animation required x ,y position of the button.right?

Comment: yes you already have buttons x and y position that you have set. use that position or manipulate that position the way you want.

Comment: No, i draw all the cells with the same position with same size.(^_^)....because buttons position is same in each cell.I want the touch that gives x and y axis.

Comment: yes but you can animate starting from the button's x and y position. or you want touch on some other position in cell? for that you will need to subclass UITableView perhaps

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the animation in different Thread.

```
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startAnimating) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add target to each button when you are creating cells means in cellForRowAtIndexPath and you can get x and y for that buttton when pressed in that action-

(UIButton*)sender.frame.origion.x

and

(UIButton*)sender.frame.origion.y